# N points are scattered at random independently of one another inside a sphere of radius R. •

Tags: probability

$N$ points are scattered at random independently of one another inside a sphere of radius $R$.   What is the probability that the distance from the center to the nearest point will not be less than $r$?  To what does the probability, found above, tend to if $R\to\infty$ and $N/R^3\to k$, where $k$ is a constant.

Comment: Say the points are $X_1,\dots,X_N$. The probability you want is just the probability that $|X_n|\ge r$ for $n=1,2,\dots, N$.

Comment: What have you tried?  What if $N=1$ for example?